# How to send embed in direct messeger

Tags: discord.py

I want to send this embed in direct. How can i send this embed in ditect?

```py
@bot.commnd()
@commands.has_role(1012777316864241694)
async def loader(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = '', colour=0x87CEEB)
    emb.set_author(name=bot.user.name)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url='')
    emb.add_field(name="", value = '', inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name="", value = '',  inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name="", value = '', inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name="", value = '', inline = False)
    emb.set_image(url ="")
    await bot.send_message(embed=emb) 
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a direct message to a use by using [Member.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20send#discord.Member.send)

To send to the command user, you can use:

```
await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)
```

All attributes of messages including embeds work no differently when sending to users.